# Accessing axis or figure in python ggplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, python-ggplot

python ggplot is great, but still new, and I find the need to fallback on traditional matplotlib techniques to modify my plots. But I'm not sure how to either pass an axis instance to ggplot, or get one back from it.

So let's say I build a plot like so:

```
import ggplot as gp
```

(explicit import)

```
p = gp.ggplot(gp.aes(x='basesalary', y='compensation'), data = df)
p + gp.geom_histogram(binwidth = 10000)
```

No problems so far. But now let's say I want the y-axis in log scale. I'd like to be able to do this:

```
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
```

Unfortunately, `plt.gca()` doesn't access the axis created by `ggplot`. I end up with two figures: the histogram from ggplot in linear scale, and an empty figure with a log-scale y axis.

I've tried a few variations with both `gca()` and `gcf()` without success.

Comment: I tried to tag this question properly but failed. I am not referring to ggplot or ggplot2 in R. See https://github.com/yhat/ggplot.

Comment: I've added a tag and a rough wiki copied from the source. Once it gets peer-reviewed it should be up. Thanks for the heads-up on this library, it looks nice!

Comment: That is odd, they use `plt.gca()` heavily in their code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might have been some changes since 2013 when this question was asked. The way to produce a matplotlib figure from a ggplot is

```
g.make()
```

after that, figure and axes can be obtained via

```
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()
```

or, if there are more axes, `axes = fig.axes`.

Then, additional features can be added in matplotlib, like also shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899779/how-can-i-add-a-pythons-ggplot-object-to-a-matplot-grid)'s answer.

Finally the plot can be saved using the usual `savefig` command.

Complete example:

```
import ggplot as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# produce ggplot
g = gp.ggplot(gp.aes(x='carat', y='price'), data=gp.diamonds)
g = g + gp.geom_point()
g = g + gp.ylab(' ')+ gp.xlab(' ')
# Make
g.make()

# obtain figure from ggplot
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()
# adjust some of the ggplot axes' parameters
ax.set_title("ggplot plot")
ax.set_xlabel("Some x label")
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

[This is outdated with current ggpy]

There is now a `scale_y_log()`. If you want to do something in `matplotlib`, you can get the current figure/axis with

```
g = ggplot(...)
fig = g.draw()
#or
g.draw() # or print(g)
fig = plt.gcf() 
ax = plt.gca()
```

Your version fails because ggplots draws the plot on `print(g)` in the `ggplot.__repr__()` method (which calls `ggplot.draw()`), so there is simple no `matplotlib` figure right after constructing the ggplot object but only after `print` (or `g.draw()`). `g.draw()` also returns the figure, so you don't need to use `plt.gcf()`

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'ggplot' object has no attribute 'draw'`.

Comment: This is because the answer was valid for ggpy before the big rewrite.  See the above answer for the current situation:https://stackoverflow.com/a/44207128/1380673

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
p = gp.ggplot(gp.aes(x='basesalary', y='compensation'), data = df)
p + gp.geom_histogram(binwidth = 10000) + gp.scale_y_log()
```

Not sure if it works just like that though, just guessing from looking at the code...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is work with matplotlib directly to modify ggplot's output. The log scaling was just an example. (FYI, I didn't find a `ggplot.scale_y_log()` when I originally wrote the question, but there could be one now.)

Comment: OK, I think I got what you mean.. I understand your orig question was from Oct '13, a lot might have changed since then, at least `gcf()` works for me now: `f = plt.gcf(); ax = f.gca(); ax.set_yscale('log'); plt.show()`

Comment: The trick in the previous comment works in an ipython interactive session, but it seems that the graphics has to be displayed, which seems to prevent the integration in a non-interactive script.