# Why is the plot generated from ggplot not showing up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am unable to display the plot from `ggplot`. I've tried something like

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from ggplot import *

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('file.csv', index_col=None)
x=df['X']
y=df['Y']
plt=ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x, y=y)) +\
    geom_line() +\
    stat_smooth(colour='blue', span=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Why is it not showing up?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is an error message: can you show it?

Comment: Also: I think that it should be g = ggplot(...) + ...; g.draw(); plt.show()

Comment: if I try that I get the error `g=ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x, y=y)) +\
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: I am not sure about this but does ggplot have a show() method ?  I have only used show() method from pyplot (matplotlib). import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. What do you get when you type plt or print plt ?

Answer (score 11):

The line `plt = ggplot(....` is not right, for a few reasons.

1. `plt` is the name you've given the `pylab` module. `plt =` will delete it!
2. `data=df` is a keyword argument (because of the `data=` part). They have to go *after* positional arguments. See [the `keyword` entry of the Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) for details. You either need to make the first argument positional by taking out `data=`, or put it after the positional argument `aes(x=x, y=y)`.
3. the `ggplot` call returns a `ggplot` object, not a `pyplot`-related thing. `ggplot` objects have `draw()` not `show()`.

The developer himself shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21268591/2071807) how it's meant to be done:

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +\
    geom_line() +\
    stat_smooth(colour='blue', span=0.2)
print(g)
# OR
g.draw()
```

That last line `g.draw()` returns a `matplotlib` figure object so you can also do:

```
fig = g.draw()
```

which will give you access to the `matplotlib` figure, if that's the sort of thing you want to do.

Comment: This was useful to me, except I found that the draw() method doesn't exist (at least with the ggplot-0.11.5-py35_1 that appears to be current).  Instead, the method is show().  Also, show() does not return anything, so you can't easily get the matplotlib figure in the manner you described.

Comment: @ybull: Same here